# How to get the Redux RootState object prior to constructing the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In [Type Checking Middleware](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-middleware), it's described how to infer the type of the RootState from the return of `combineReducers`.

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ ... });
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

This is very useful for retrieving the type, however I would like runtime information of the return value; specifically my RootState is an object with key/value pairs, and I would like to iterate over those key/value pairs *prior* to the `configureStore(...)` call. I would like to do something like

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ ... });
const rootState = rootReducer();

const keys = Object.keys(rootState);
keys.map(...)
```

in a type safe way.